# How to make a variable optional inside a Template String?

Tags: javascript, string

I am passing a variable inside a template string that may be uninitialized.

```js
let name;
console.log(`Hello ${name}, How are you?`);
```

Now when I run this it returns

> Hello undefined, How are you?

Depending on the situation i want it to omit variable from the string. Like

> Hello, How are you?

This can be circumvented using if statement but that's not what I am looking for.
I am looking for a direct approach. Something like

```js
console.log(`Hello ${name || null}`)
```

Comment: What is the problem? You have an solution right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### You can use the: [Nullish coalescing operator (??)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_operator)

**Example #1:**

```js
let name;
console.log(`Hello ${name ?? ""}, How are you?`); // Hello , How are you?
```

**Example #2:**

```js
let name = "fishLegs";
console.log(`Hello ${name ?? ""}, How are you?`); // Hello fishLegs, How are you?
```

---

If the space between the `Hello` and  `,` bothers you, you can use:

```js
let name;
console.log(`Hello${name ? " " : ""}${name ?? ""}, How are you?`); // Hello fishLegs, How are you?

name = "fishLegs";
console.log(`Hello${name ? " " : ""}${name ?? ""}, How are you?`); // Hello fishLegs, How are you?
```

Comment: That's what i was looking for. Never knew about this operator. Thx

Comment: console.log(`Hello ${name || ""}`) -  the one you have is working same if you replace null with ""

Comment: @GokulnathP Space is not added by operator. Space was already in front of the variable.

Comment: @GokulnathP That space is not added by it, it is the space just before it and after the `hello`

Comment: @fishLegs I have updated it... if the space bothers you.

Comment: Yes, i didn't meant operator is adding, i meant it is not taken care in the solution

Comment: @GokulnathP I have updated it... if the space bothers you.

Comment: No, it is not bothers me, i just mention is that what @fishLegs expect.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of null putting "" will work

```js
let name;
console.log(`Hello ${name || ""}, How are you?`)
```

To remove space we need if,

```js
let name;
console.log(`Hello${name ? " " + name : ""}, How are you?`)
```

Comment: It will not work if `name = false;` or `name = 0;`. It just returns `Hello, How are you?` but it should be `Hello false, How are you?` or `Hello 0, How are you?`. That is why `??` this is better,